# Visual Studio 2012 C# Building Final Setup for Publishing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installation, exe

I have built a windows application on VS2012 (C#) with the following features

```
1. Codes accessing pictures from project resources folder.
2. Codes accessing other multimedia (like videos, txt, sounds, etc) using something like: addr = @directoryName + "\\videos\\*.mp4".
```

Hence, I've added few folders in my Debug folder which I require to be in the same directory level as my main .exe file. All works fine on the debug mode, and even while running the .exe without debug mode.

Then I created my application setup (a 1.8GB setup file including all resources needed) using Inno Setup Compiler and it works like magic on the same computer, but not on another.

I was then curious whether the problem is with the setup or the .exe. So I tried copying the whole project folder into another laptop of mine, ran the .exe file on the debug folder, but nope, nothing came. Checked the Task Manager and found out that my .exe was running for 5 seconds under the Processes Tab, then it just disappeared.
(Similar to the problem stated here: [Not able to run the .exe file created from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223857/not-able-to-run-the-exe-file-created-from-c-sharp)).

Note: .NET Framework 4.5 have been installed perfectly on the other machine and all files needed have been copied.

So now I'm faced with two major issues:
- First, **my .exe is not running on another machine**.
- Second, **which folders to include** on my setup file as I do not want to include the .cs files and the other source codes. Just enough for my users to run my app flawlessly. Tried Inno (best one), InstallShield and had a quick glance at WIX.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Been working, searching and doing trial and errors on making the setup file for almost 2 weeks now. Thanks in advance!
Regards,

Ken

Comment: What does "not running" mean?  Do you get errors, exceptions?

Comment: @PeterRitchie As stated above, nothing came. Process was running for few secs, then it just disappeared without showing anything.

Comment: Check the event log, there should be an entry for the app if it crashed.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Silly me, I didn't notice that there is an error.txt generated. It was showing could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs'
Well, the problem has been solved after downloading the required assembly. Thanks a lot!

Just a question though, how is it that we can determine what all the assemblies and plugins that the user may require and in turn provide an option to download them? Maybe certain codes can be used to identify those? Because I was just testing in one laptop. Another machine may miss another assembly, which is undesirable
Thanks again beforehand!